# Login with other fields using Auth in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Problem regarding login with Auth in cakephp3

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Articles',
                'action' => 'index'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            ]
        ]);
```

it only allows me to use username by default, Okay If I wanted to login using email, that through I have searched and got this:
UserController.php

```
 public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) 
        {
            $this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
                    'Form' => [
                        'fields' => ['username' => 'email']
                    ]
                ]);
            $this->Auth->constructAuthenticate();
            $this->request->data['email'] = $this->request->data['username'];
            unset($this->request->data['username']);
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) 
            {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
```

I can change fields from username to email and reconstruct it but What if I wanted to login with `ID` field.

```
$this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
                    'Form' => [
                        'fields' => ['username' => 'id']
                    ]
                ]);
```

If I change from email to id, it is not allowing me to login. Do I have to use then queries instead?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and solved it like this using cakePHP 3.3

Your AppController

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email',
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'loginAction' => [
        'controller' => 'Users',
        'action' => 'login'
    ],
    'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer(),
    'loginRedirect' => [
        'plugin' => false,
        'controller' => 'Pages',
        'action' => 'home',
    ],
]);
```

Your UserController (login action)

```
/**
 * @return Response|null
 */
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect.');
    }
}
```

Your basic Users/login.ctp template

```
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('email') ?>
<?= $this->Form->input('password') ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('Login') ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, when you changed the 'email' field to 'id' in the below code,

```
`('authenticate', ['Form' => ['fields' => ['username' => 'id']]]);`
```

you should have changed the input field of your view 'login.ctp'.

from this:    `<?= $this->Form->input('email') ?>`

to this:    `<?= $this->Form->input('id') ?>`